# NSString Memory Leak Issues

Tags: objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios4

I am creating global strings like this:

```
NSString *total = nil;
```

Is there another way to alloc memory to a string but set it to nil?

Comment: What do you mean "alloc memory to a string but set it to nil"? What is it you want to accomplish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are wanting to create a global string then use the extern keyword outside of a class interface.
So before your @interface declaration in your .h file, place something like

```
extern NSString *total;
```

Then in your .m file, before the @implementation declaration place something like

```
total = @"";
```

Otherwise if it's going inside a class somewhere then a simple:

```
NSString *total = [[NSString alloc] init];
```

should suffice.

I normally only use global strings as constants for NSNotifications, everything else can usually find a place in a singleton instance. Depending on what you're trying to achieve you may want to look into that in the Cocoa Programming Guide.

Comment: You can't initialize globals to a non-constant value (e.g. i.e. the result of a method or function, such as `alloc`).

Comment: Yes, however you can inside a class implementation, as in making them instance variables (not global at all). I thought I'd add that into the answer anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

I guess if you allocate the global variables in one of the implement classes. I think you can release it in your AppDelegate function
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application {

first check whether it is allocated. And release it

if(total!=nil){
 [total release];
}